# Spritekit best way to get sprites scene inside of SKSpriteNode subclass

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm subclassing SKSpritenode and need reference to the sprite's scene.  Is there a way to detect when the sprite has been added to the scene.

```
let gameScene = self.scene as GameScene
```

doing this inside init throws optional error since my sprite has been instantiated but not added to the scene.  How do I tell when my sprite has been added to the scene so I can set the property?

Comment: after you've added it, call a custom method on your custom sprite subclass

Comment: ah ok.. just figured there might be a prettier way of doing this.. I'll have to create a custom method for all my classes.. or i guess give them one superclass

Comment: you could override addChild but there you'll have to call the super implementation, and you may not want to run the custom code for every addchild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I create `addToNode:(SKNode *)parentNode` method to handle that:

```
- (void)addtoNode:(SKNode *)parentNode {
     [parentNode addChild:self];
     // Do what you need here
}
```

Comment: another great approach

Answer (score 0):

Just use a guard

```
guard let scene = self.scene as? GameScene
else
{
    return
}
//Everything beyond here is safe to use scene
```